# copy files found by "find" to another folder

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I want to copy shared libraries found by following command in a certain folder (/path/to/folder/). How can I do this in bash?

```
find /usr/lib/python2.7/ -name '*.so' -exec ldd {} \;
```

Comment: What does `ldd` have to do with this question?

Comment: @EtanReisner, he appears to want to copy the shared libraries on which Python shared libraries *depend*, which he is identifying via `ldd`.  He might do this, for example, to create a self-contained application bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xargs` to the rescue.

```
find /usr/lib/python2.7/ -name '*.so' -exec ldd {} \; |
xargs -r cp -t where/is/destination
```

This ends up effectively collecting the output from `ldd` to the end of the `cp` command line.

This will only work correctly if the file names do not contain newlines.  Some legacy versions of `xargs` also need additional options if the input file names may contain whitespace.